# Error when trying to deploy Vue project through Vercel

Tags: vue.js, node-modules, vercel

I've been trying to deploy my Vue project using vercel, but keep running in to the following errors in the deployment logs. I understand this might be to do with the node version i'm using (12.18.3) and sass, but can't figure out the fix.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /vercel/path0/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /node16/bin/node /vercel/path0/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! make: Entering directory `/vercel/path0/node_modules/node-sass/build'
npm ERR!   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/vercel/.node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node -I/vercel/.node-gyp/16.14.0/src -I/vercel/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/openssl/config -I/vercel/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/vercel/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/uv/include -I/vercel/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/zlib -I/vercel/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
```

Comment: You're using node 12 and here you're getting node 16 error, it might be an error because of node-sass package version not supported in node 16

Comment: Thanks! That sent me down the right path and I was able to resolve.